# How to connect to a device on the same LAN and different subnet

Tags: networking, ip, routing, modem, subnet

This may sound a stupid question...
I have an ADSL wireless modem. My phone and a router are connected to it (Router is wired to a LAN port).
These are assigned IPs:
Modem: 192.168.1.1
Router: 192.168.1.2 (From Modem's DHCP client list)
Phone: 192.168.1.3
I have a PC connected to the router. But the PC's IP is 192.168.2.2
My router's config page is accessible from the PC at address 192.168.2.1 but not from my phone even at address 192.168.1.2.
ADSL modem's config page is accessible both on PC and Phone at 192.168.1.1.
My question is: How can I connect to PC and use it's shared files & printer from my phone? and is my configuration correct? (this is default configuration and all devices are connected to the internet)

Comment: (Router is wired to a LAN port) :You need to turn DHCP off on this router as your router is performing DHCP services. You probably have two DHCP servers running

Comment: Can I set every Device's IP manually on 192.168.1.X ragne? Turning off DHCP on router didn't help. Setting IPs manually didn't work either. But is it possible to have every IP in one range?

Comment: If you have one (only) DHCP Server then all IP addresses will be in one range

Comment: Then the router will act like a switch. Right?

Comment: More or less Yes. I hook up routers way and no issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to connect to PC from my phone by defining a virtual server. I added my PC's IP address to router's virtual server list. Now I can access my PC using router's IP address.